# Changing Grunt config variable through command line

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, gruntjs

I have two different paths where I want to compile the mobile vs desktop code. I would like to alternate by passing a grunt parameter in the command line.

```
/**
 * @module Build
 * @class Build.Config
 * @static
 */

module.exports = function(grunt) {

var config = {};

    var NewPath;

    var env = grunt.option('target') || "Mobile";


    if (env == "Desktop") {  // MAKE THIS DYNAMIC WITH COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT
        newPath = "source/desktop/";
    }
    else {
       newPath = "source/mobile/";
    }

config.root = newPath;
config.stylesheets = config.root + '/stylesheets';
config.javascripts = config.root + '/javascripts';
config.images = config.root + '/images';
config.jsbin = config.javascripts + '/generated';
config.cssbin = config.stylesheets + '/generated';
config.docsbin = 'docs';



// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    'beautifier': {
        'options': {
            'indentSize': 1,
            'indentChar': '\t',
            'spaceAfterAnonFunction': true
        }
    },

    'beautify': {
        'files': [ config.javascripts + '/app/**/*.js' ]
    },

    'requirejs': require('./build/config/requirejs.js')(config),

    'watch': require('./build/config/watch.js')(config),
    'stylus':require('./build/config/stylus.js')(config)

});


// Default task.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['stylus:compile','requirejs']);      
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['stylus:dev']);

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I was doing it right I just needed to pass in the variable for env correctly:

$  grunt --target="Desktop"

Answer (score 0):

An alternate to --option is to pass it through the colon. for example passing it to jshint

```bsh
grunt jshint:desktop
```

Then configure grunt to pick up that command line argument using `process.argv` and you can use it to configure your paths or whatever else might be needed:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

   //dynamic config after the ':'. 'desktop' here
    var env = process.argv[2].split(':')[1]; 


    var config = {
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                "force": true
            }
        },
    };

    //...

    config.jshint[env] = { // ex:  $ grunt jshint:desktop
      src: ['public/'+env+'/js/main.js']
    };

    //...

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig(config);

    //...
};
```

One caveat on using `process` is that it won't work when you use a grunt task that respawns your process like the useful [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent). In that case it's bettter to go with [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) as shown by @im_benton. passing `grunt mytask --myvar=myval` and picking it up in you Gruntfile.js as `grunt.option('myvar')`  `